# Get Twitter feeds inJSON format

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, twitter

I want to get twitter feed using a single url whose output should be in JSON format containing latest twitter feed. I am using below URL to get it
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/johnrobertpett.json

but it is not working.

Can any one please suggest?

Comment: It's stupid that this is so hard to find. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

We can not get tweets directly by simply opening a URL, That was possible in earlier version of twitter 1 now We need to use REST API to get the Timeline data in JSON FORMAT

Comment: not a complete answer . not enough here to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You need this URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

And of course send parameters and authentication data [according to the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Comment: How to send authentication data in above url u mentioned? Can you please provide me any example

Comment: @toddmo posting a complete answer would mean implementing the entire OAuth token-sequence, somehting thats been shown many times before and is well documented here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests